# Observability addon problem? how to add new targets.?

Tags: prometheus, microk8s, observability

I have enabled observability addon in microk8s cluster, now i want to add new targets to prometheus for scraping, but i cant find the required configuration file, (eg prometheus.yaml). Can anyone guide me with this?
the version i am using is
MicroK8s v1.29.0 revision 6364
Client Version: v1.29.0
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.29.0

I tried to get the config file using kubectl get cm -A, but i did not find the required yaml file

Answer (score 0):

It's in a configmap. I have the same microk8s version as you. It is named prometheus-kube-prom-stack-kube-prome-prometheus-rulefiles-0 on my system.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).